# How to dynamically decide the URL of translation tables dynamically with angular-translate custom loader?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

#### How to dynamically decide the URL of translation tables dynamically with `$translateProvider`

Currently, we follow - 
[https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading](asynchronous loading) in one of our application.We have followed this method for almost 2 years.But,right now we face a different task.We have to decide the URL of our translation file based on a logic.The logic is as follows,
if file exists in given `location` then resolve translation through it or else fallback to `default location`.

#### My current environment

- version of angular-translate - 2.4.2 with angular-translate-partial-loader - 2.4.2
- version of angular - 1.5

#### Structure of App

```
|-- mod 1
|   |-- de_de.json
|   |-- en_us.json
|   |-- es_es.json
|   `-- zh_tw.json
|-- mod 2
|   |-- de_de.json
...Followed by corresponding translation files.
```

#### Code structure:

application.js

```
myapp.config(['$translateProvider', '$translatePartialLoaderProvider',function ( $translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider ) {
    $translateProvider.useLoader( '$translatePartialLoader', {
        urlTemplate: 'i18n/{part}/{lang}.json'
    } );
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage( "en_us" );
    $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage( "en_us" );
}]);
........
myapp.run( function ( $rootScope, $translate, editableOptions ) {
    $rootScope.$on( '$translatePartialLoaderStructureChanged', function () {
        $translate.refresh();
    } );
    editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
} );
```

controller1.js

```
myapp.controller1("Controller1",function($scope, ...,.., $translate, $translatePartialLoader,$rootScope) {
    /*@ngInject*/
    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('login');
    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('home');
.......
 $scope.setLanguage = function(lang) {
     $translate.use(lang);
    }
```

So far so good.Now we want to change the logic of `application.js` to generate the translation table resolving URL.We have to check if we have translation tables for a `particular_part/in_particular_language` .

#### Expected Structure and behavior

```
|-- mod 1
|  |-- Custom
|  |  |-- de_de.json
|  |  |........followed by all custom translations for mod1 i.e, $translatePartialLoader.addPart('mod1') 
|  |-- en_us.json
|  |-- es_es.json
|   `-- zh_tw.json
|-- mod 2
|   |-- de_de.json
```

In the new structure we will have Custom directory under each module,if there exists a translation file for a part/module in Custom then resolve using `part/Custom/lang_key.json else fall back to part/lang_key.json(as before)`

How can we achieve this through `ng-translate` ? .

The approach I have gone ahead is by writing a [custom loader](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/13_custom-loaders) .But the `options` of the `$translatePartialLoader` restricts the argument only to  lang_key which is passed by `$translate.use(lang_key)` .How can we get the `mod1` passed to `$translatePartialLoader.addPart('mod1')` into out `customLoader`.We cannot pass it to `$translate.use('lang_key/mod1')` as we call `$translate.use('land_key')` only once when the user logs in.

If we can get the added module from `$translatePartialLoader('mod1')` call,passed into our `customLoader` then based on logic we can resolve translations accordingly.Currently, I am stuck on how to get the added part into `customLoader` as it is loaded by controllers(controller 1..).Is there a way or a custom service which should be written to get the added part/module.. into our `customLoader` if yes,can you guide me or help me with relevant code OR will we have to change the entire structure of the app - if changing the structure will help,then what the structure should be ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A custom service to grab the Part or Module selected by the User.

```
myapp.factory('fetchLanguagePart', function ($q, $timeout) {
/*@ngInject*/
var languageService = {};
languageService.languagePart = ['defaultmod1', 'defaultmod2'];  //Translation tables from these parts are always required.

languageService.getLanguagePart = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var url = purl();
    var part = grabbedPart;

    //Logic for part deciding.

    languageService.languagePart = part;
    return part;
}
return languageService;
})
```

Config

```
myapp.config(['$translateProvider', '$translatePartialLoaderProvider', function ($translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {

    //Default language loader.

    // $translateProvider.useLoader( '$translatePartialLoader', {
    //  urlTemplate: 'i18n/{part}/{lang}.json'
    // } );

    //Custom language loader for angular-translate.

    $translateProvider.useLoader('customLanguageTemplateLoader', {})
    $translateProvider.forceAsyncReload(true);
    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy();
}]);
```

CustomLoader it fetches default module translation tables and custom module translation tables and merges them and passes it to angular-translate.

```
myapp.factory('customLanguageTemplateLoader', function ($q, $http, fetchLanguagePart, $timeout) {
/*@ngInject*/
return function (options) {

    var getCustomLanguagePath = function (part) {
        return 'i18n/' + part + '/Custom/' + options.key + '.json';
    }
    var getFallBackLanguagePath = function (part) {
        return 'i18n/' + part + '/' + options.key + '.json';
    }
    //To fetch default part translations and then merge with custom part translations
    var fetchPartTranslations = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var responses;
        var part = fetchLanguagePart.getLanguagePart();
        var customLanguageUrl = getCustomLanguagePath(part);
        var fallbackLanguageUrl = getFallBackLanguagePath(part);
        $http.get(fallbackLanguageUrl).success(function (fallbackResult) {
            responses = fallbackResult;
            $http.get(customLanguageUrl).success(function (customResult) {
                var updatedResult = angular.extend(responses, customResult);
                angular.extend(responses, customResult);
                deferred.resolve(responses);
            }).error(function (error) {
                deferred.resolve(responses);
            })
        })
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var part = fetchLanguagePart.getLanguagePart();
    var customLanguageUrl = getCustomLanguagePath(part);
    var fallbackLanguageUrl = getFallBackLanguagePath(part);
    var responses;

    //To fetch default module translation tables merge it with custom module translations and then merge the result of the two with  part translations.

    $http.get(getFallBackLanguagePath('home')).success(function (fallBackHome) {
        responses = fallBackHome;
        $http.get(getCustomLanguagePath('home')).success(function (customHomeResult) {
            var updatedResult = angular.extend(responses, customHomeResult);
            fetchPartTranslations().then(function (partTranslations) {
                angular.extend(responses, partTranslations);
                angular.extend(responses, customHomeResult);
                deferred.resolve(responses);
            });
        }).error(function (error) {
            fetchPartTranslations().then(function (partTranslations) {
                angular.extend(responses, partTranslations);
                deferred.resolve(responses);
            });
        })
    })
    return deferred.promise;
}
})
```